# How to define a variable in vue component ? (Vue.JS 2)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My vue component is like this :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="panel-group"v-for="item in list">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="alert">
                    {{ status = item.received_at ? item.received_at : item.rejected_at }}
                    <p v-if="status">
                        {{ status }} - {{ item.received_at ? 'Done' : 'Cancel' }}
                    </p>
                    <p v-else>
                        Proses
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        ...
        computed: {
            list: function() {
                return this.$store.state.transaction.list
            },
            ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want define the `status` variable

So, the `status` variable can be used in condition

I try like this :

```
{{ status = item.received_at ? item.received_at : item.rejected_at }}
```

But, seems it was wrong

How I define it correctly?

Comment: why don't you use a `getter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a method to have the functionality as the `item` variable would not be present outside the scope of the `v-for`

```
 ...
 <div class="alert">
   <p v-if="status(item)">
      {{ status(item) }} - {{ item.received_at ? 'Done' : 'Cancel' }}
   </p>
   <p v-else>
      Proses
   </p>
 </div> 
 ...
```

and in the component:

```
methods: {
  ...
  status (item) {
    return (item) 
             ? (item.received_at) ? item.received_at : item.rejected_at
             : false
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: `item.received_at` taken from the loop `<div class="panel-group"v-for="item in list">`. It is not readable in the `computed`

Comment: `item` must be a data property?

Comment: `data() {
            return {
                item: this.$store.state.transaction.list
            }
        },`. Like that?

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. But seems it remains to be defined in the `data ()`

Comment: @samueltoh does adding the computed `status()` not help?

Comment: Yes. It does not work. There exist error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'received_at' of undefined`. Seems because `this.item.received_at` was called outside the loop `<div class="panel-group"v-for="item in list">`

Comment: @samueltoh check the `this.$store.state.transaction`

Comment: If I add : `console.log(this.$store.state.transaction.list)`, the result : https://postimg.org/image/4ff5ka345/

Comment: I think the `this.$store.state.transaction` is empty when you are adding it to data, try having `item` too as computed.

Comment: I'm still confused to solve my problem. Seems, it must define in loop `<div class="panel-group"v-for="item in list">`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `data` :

```
export default {
    ...
    data: function() {
        return {
            status: false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        list: function() {
            return this.$store.state.transaction.list
        },
        ...
    }
}
```