# How to calculate the total in vue component ? Vue.JS 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My vue component, you can see below :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="panel-group" v-for="item in list">
            ...
            {{ total = 0 }}
            <tr v-for="product in item.products">
                ...
                <td>
                    <b>Price</b><br>
                    <span>{{ product.quantity * product.price }}</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{ total += (product.quantity * product.price) }}
            <tr>
            <td colspan="3" class="text-right">
                <b>Total: {{ total }} </b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        computed: {
            list: function() {
                return this.$store.state.transaction.list
            },
            ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

I try like above code

But, seems it still wrong

How can I solve it correctly?

I'm still newbie in vue.js 2

Comment: Can you also mention what went wrong?

Comment: Put `total` in data like I mention few minutes ago... http://stackoverflow.com/a/43207980/7577617

Comment: you are accessing product outside of your loop

Comment: @Amresh Venugopal, See answer from Frank Provost. I try it

Comment: Your product is being accessed outside the `v-for` `{{ total += (product.quantity * product.price) }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, `TypeError: this.$store.state.transaction.list.reduce is not a function` is an error marked in Frank's answer I presume `this.$store.state.transaction.list` is not an `Array` but an `object` as `v-for` iterates through both.

```
total: function() { 
  var list = this.$store.state.transaction.list 
  var sum = 0 
  for(var listProps in list) { 
    list[listProps].products.forEach(function (product) { 
    sum += product.pivot.quantity * product.pivot.price 
    }) 
  } 
  return sum; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another computed property

```
<script>
    export default {
        ...
        computed: {
            list: function() {
                return this.$store.state.transaction.list
            },
            total: function() {
                return this.$store.state.transaction.list.reduce(function(sum, item) {
                    sum += item.products.reduce(function(tmp, product) { tmp += product.quantity * product.price; return tmp; }, 0);
                    return sum;
                }, 0);
            }
            ...
        }
    }
</script>
```

Use a nested Array.reduce to get the total of your structure where the list has many items and an item has many products

Comment: There exist error : `TypeError: this.$store.state.transaction.list.reduce is not a function`

Comment: then most probably it's not an array yet / initialized. You can add a check for that before returning the stuff:
 if (this.$store.state.transaction.list && Array.isArray(this.$store.state.transaction.list)) ...

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot